# PHP Iterating through array error

Tags: php

I have a question about the following code:

PHP function, takes in an array, recursively cycles through each level, does a string replace if single quote found and returns back array.

```
function escape_quote($data)
{
    $clean = array();

    foreach ($data as $key=>$val)
    {
        if (is_array($val))
        {
             $clean[$key] = escape_quote($val);
        } else {
             $val = str_replace("'", "''", $val);
             $clean[$key] = $val;
            }
    }

    return $clean;
}
```

Here is the array of data I am passing:

```
$vars = array
(
    'customer1' => array
    (
        'fname' => 'John',
        'lname' => "D'oe"
    ),
    'customer2' => array
    (
        'name'  => array
        (
            'fname' => 'John',
            'lname' => "D'oe"
        ),
        'address'   => '1234 street',
        'phone'     => '1234567899'

    )
);
```

I make this call to the function and pass the array to it:

```
$output = escape_quote($vars);
print_r($output);
```

My output on the screen:

Array ( [customer1] => Array ( [fname] => John [lname] => D''oe ) [customer2] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [fname] => John [lname] => D'oe ) [address] => 1234 street [phone] => 1234567899 ) )

My questions is why am I not getting the second "D'oe" returned as "D''oe"

if I echo out each value in the function rather than add to the clean array it will add the second "'" to both "D'oe". I am not sure what is missing... please help.

**UPDATE:**

I figured out the issue, made update to code. If the $val was an array I wasn't setting the $clean[$key] back equal to escape_quote($val).

Comment: "escape_quote($val);" - you don't assign the result to anything.

Comment: Please see my updates, I wasn't assigning the iteration equal to the clean array if $val was an array. Works now, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
function escape_quote($data)
{
    $clean = array();

    foreach ($data as $key=>$val)
    {
        $set = false;
        if (is_array($val))
        {
            $set = true;
            $val = escape_quote($val);
        }
        if(!$set){
            $val = str_replace("'", "''", $val);
        }
        $clean[$key] = $val;
    }

return $clean;
}
```